# Binding database resultset array into a comma seperated string in php

Tags: php, string

I have an array which is an output of a database query like this(in JSON format) :

```
[  
 {  
  "id":1,
  "name":"Category group sidebar",
  "location":"category_group_sidebar",
  "width":250,
  "height":225
  },
{  
  "id":2,
  "name":"Category sidebar",
  "location":"category_sidebar",
  "width":250,
  "height":225
  } 
]
```

I want this result to be appended with following string and results to be comma separated as following:

```
The ad space names are Category group sidebar,Category sidebar and the dimensions are 250,225
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (can't test):

```
$json = json_decode($json_data, true);

$insert = "";

foreach ($json as $data) {
  $insert .= $data['name'] . ",";
}

$insert = rtrim($insert, ",");

$text = "The ad space names are {$insert} and the dimensions are 250,225"
```

New response:

```
$json = json_decode($json_data, true);

$insert = "";

foreach ($json as $data) {
  $insert .= $data['name'] . " with dimension " . $data['width'] . "*" . $data['height'] . ",";
}

$insert = rtrim($insert, ",");

$text = "Ad spaces are, {$insert}"
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks.
I want this format too : "Ad spaces are, Category group sidebar with dimension 250*225, Category sidebar with dimensions 250*225"

Comment: I have edited the answer. You simply need to concatenate the strings to make what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This will take all properties found within the array of each array, join the inner array by space, the outer array created by array_map will be joined with comma.

```
$jsonData = json_decode($yourJsonData, true);
$output = implode(", ", array_map($jsonData, function(item) { return implode(" ", $item); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = json_decode($json_array);
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
 if(!isset($str)){
   $str= $value['name']; 
 }else{
   $str= ",".$value['name'];
 }
}
$string = "The ad space names are ".$str" and the dimensions are 250,225";
echo $string;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.